# how to display a video from a JList?

Tags: swing, jlist

I am currently doing an application using Swing and i am stuck at a certain point. In my function, i have to link videos from a JList. The problem is i am not sure how to link the videos from the JList. I am using an OpenBrowser class to link the video to the internet. I did consider using  JButton but i would have to hardcode it and that would be ugly. Is there any other alternatives to do this? I am in desperate need and would be eternally grateful to whoever that can help me.

Safa :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to open a browser with the video using a selection listener, you can consider the idea of launching it with a double click on a JList entry.

sample code

```
String[] items = {"i1", "i2", "i3", "i4"};
JList list = new JList(items);

list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        JList list = (JList)evt.getSource();
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {  //check if it is a Double-click

            int index = list.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
            // do whatever you want with the entry at that index
        }
    }
});
```

Desktp classes to browse some site (sample code):

```
if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
    URI uri = new URI("http://www.google.com");
    desktop.browse(uri);
}
```

The `desktop.browse()` call will open your favourite browser with the given URL.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. Can you explain to me what is a selection listener? i'm a first year student so i am still unfamilliar with certain terms. Please and thank you.

Comment: in java swing if you want to "trigger something" when a particular event happen you have to use the appropriate listener. If you want to handle the event "Hey, someone selected a row of your JList right now!" you have to write your ListSelectionListener, read the correct documentation for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html

Comment: Hi. thanks for explaining! it was helpful but now my question is how do i link the JList to the internet? if i was to use the OpenBrowser method to link to the internet, do i link it at the 

int index = list.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());

do i link the open Browser class here or is there another alternative?

Comment: Hi, i think my question is not very clear so i'll rephrase it so you can understand better. At this point, i am able to display the list of videos that i hard-coded from your code however, in the actual 
function, i would have to retrieve the videos from the database and display it in the Internet. I have already tried launching it with a double click on a JList entry but from there i am not sure how to go to the internet. Is there any other alternatives to do this? I am in desperate need and would be eternally grateful to whoever that can help me.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? If it's 6 I've a good news for you: you can use the Desktop API (here the documentation: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/ ), look at my answer, I've just added some code. I don't now how can I help you more than this :-)